# getimagesize() returns incorrect height for an animated GIF

Tags: php, getimagesize

In my PHP debugger (at a breakpoint) I unambiguously observe that the PHP function `getimagesize()` returns the incorrect height for an animated GIF.  Opening the GIF in IrfanView reveals the proper height (266 x 199 pixels).  However, `getimagesize()` reports the dimensions to be 266 x 353 px (indices 0 and 1, respectively, of the array returned from `getimagesize()`).

(The bits per pixel returned by `getimagesize()` is also incorrect - it's reported as 5, instead of 8 - but http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php indicates that this is to be expected for an animated GIF.)

Can someone please explain to me why `getimagesize()` is failing in this scenario, and what workaround might be available.

Comment: In a local directory.  But, here is a link to it (I just copied it into a publicly visible URL): http://www.opalwand.com/TestAnimatedGif.GIF

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may have to do with the Canvas Size of the GIF as defined by the GIF header. The header could be sending the wrong size and PHP will be grabbing that. You can check on the headers manually using Image Magic.

More info on this topic here: http://www.mombu.com/php/php/t-28432-getimagesize-return-incorect-width-height-10147509-last.html

Hope That helps.

Comment: Indeed, it was a canvas size-related issue.  The image had previously been cropped (if I recall correctly - perhaps not cropped, but something along those lines); however, the canvas size had not been changed.